# Problem with compiling a hikari discord bot to an exe

Tags: python, discord, bots, filenotfounderror

Recently, I have tried to compile a **hikari** discord bot to an exe (because many computers may not have a python interpreter installed), I tried **pyinstaller**, **py2exe** and **autopytoexe** though none of them worked. When I ran the exe they all returned the same error message of: **"FileNotFoundError: D:\MyDir\dist\library.aip/hikari/banner.txt"** or something like that. They all had an issue with a hikari file not begin found. So I am wondering if there is anything I could do with my code or with settings so that I can compile this hikari bot to an exe. Or should I rewrite the program in a different

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I avoided using to exe compilers and instead just included a python interpreter with hikari installed to run the python source code.

Answer (score 0):

did you already try to add 'banner.txt' in the 'Additional Files' menu in Auto Py to Exe

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't know all of the different files that hikari might require, so if you could provide a list of all the additional files that hikari needs for a exe that would help alot thanks!